# Unable to enable Azure Defender Plan

Tags: azure

I need to enable Azure defender plan for my subscription ( EA ) . i'm Owner of this subscription.
But i got  javascript error when i hit save after define services .

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties')
    at lV1h5UH6pkvF.js:28:27861
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at d._checkForDowngradeEvent (lV1h5UH6pkvF.js:28:27701)
    at d.<anonymous> (lV1h5UH6pkvF.js:28:27138)
    at s (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:17:2634)
    at Object.next (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:17:1927)
    at 0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:17:1850
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:17:1644)
    at d._saveChanges (lV1h5UH6pkvF.js:28:26951)
    at Object.saveChanges (lV1h5UH6pkvF.js:28:20653)
    at Object.execute (lV1h5UH6pkvF.js:25:1129)
    at n.invoke (FrDcaNKPuP17.js:34:21430)
    at Array.<anonymous> (FrDcaNKPuP17.js:36:4361)
    at n.handleMessage (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:5685)
    at n.handleEventMessage (FrDcaNKPuP17.js:36:4663)
    at Array.<anonymous> (FrDcaNKPuP17.js:36:6857)
    at n.handleMessage (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:5685)
    at _handleMessage (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:11863)
    at p (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:1489)
    at n._handler (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:12133)
    at n._processInnerList (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:4432)
    at n._processOuterList (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:4684)
    at n.addItem (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:4867)
    at MessagePort._handleMessage (0vDMk2KjBH7c.js:80:6191)
```

Comment: contact the support if this a general issue. Else use a other browser without any plugins

Comment: i think , it was general issue. It's work fine now .  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Azure PowerShell:
Use the following Azure PowerShell command to enable Microsoft Defender for Cloud, e.g. for virtual machines:

```
Set-AzSecurityPricing -Name "virtualmachines" -PricingTier "Standard"
```

Comment: that's an commentary not a answer?